# linux strace: How to filter system calls that take more than a second

Tags: linux, strace

I'm using "strace -f -T -tt -o foo.txt -p 1234" to print the time spent in system calls. This makes the output file huge, is there a way to just print the system calls that took greater than 1second. I can grep it out from the file later, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If we simply omit the `-o foo.txt` argument, the output goes to standard output.  We can pipe it through grep and redirect to the file:

```
strace -f -T -tt  -p 1234 | grep pattern > foo.txt
```

To watch the output at the same time:

```
strace -f -T -tt  -p 1234 | grep pattern | tee foo.txt
```

If a command prints only to a file that is passed as an argument, and we want to filter/redirect its output, the first step is to check whether it implements the dash convention: can you specify standard input or output using `-` as a filename argument:

```
some_command - | our_pipe > file.txt
```

If not, then the recourse is to use Bash process substitution substitution syntax: `>(output command)` and `<(input command)`:

```
some_command >(our_pipe > file.txt)
```

The process substitution syntax expands into a token that is suitable as a filename argument for a command or function. When the program opens that token, it gets a file descriptor to the command's input or output, depending on direction.

With process substitution, we can redirect the input or output of stubborn programs which work only with files passed as by name as arguments, and which do not support any convention for requesting that standard input or output be used in place of a file.

The token used by process substitution is platform-dependent; we can see what it is using `echo`. For instance on GNU/Linux, Bash takes advantage of the `/dev/fd` operating system feature:

```
$ echo <(ls -l)
/dev/fd/63
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
strace -T command 2>&1 >/dev/null | awk '{gsub(/[<>]/,"",$NF)}$NF+.0>1.0'
```

Explanation:

- `strace -T` adds the time spent in the syscall end the end of the line, enclosed in `<...>`
- `2>&1 >/dev/null | awk` pipes stderr to `awk`. (`strace` writes it's output to stderr!)
- The `awk` command removes the `<>` from the last field `$NF` and prints lines where the time spent is higher than a second.

Probably you'll also want to pass the threshold as a variable to the awk command:

```
strace -T command 2>&1 >/dev/null \
  | awk -v thres=0.001 '{gsub(/[<>]/,"",$NF)}$NF+.0>thres+.0'
```